# SharePoint Search + BCS and meaningless non-human-readable urls

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, external

Indexing an external content type is pretty straight forward.
However I find it very troublesome to figure out the specific "crawl state" of a particular item.

Looking at the "Url View" inside SharePoint CA it shows me all my crawled/indexed items. **Unfortunately the url part is nowhere near readable.** So I have no clue where to look for my specific item in question.

**Example:**

```
bdc3://adventureworksdbtest/Default/00000000%2D0000%2D0000%2D0000%2D000000000000/418/AdventureworksDB/420?s_id=i0QMAAA==&s_ce=0408808680g000g10204000g0o20003s
```

**Guid.Empty?

418?

420?

Some encoded id?** (it's not BASE64. i0QMAAA== translates to nothing).

The AdventureWorks product table has a productID (int) and a name (string). In my BDC model I mapped the "Title" column to the product's "Name" column for my Product entity. See below...

```
<Entity Name="Product" Namespace="Rs.Exp.IndexingConnector.BuiltinDbConnector" Version="1.0.0.1">
  <Properties>
    <Property Name="OriginalName" Type="System.String">[Production].[Product]</Property>
    <Property Name="EntitySetName" Type="System.String">[Production].[Product]</Property>
    <Property Name="Title" Type="System.String">Name</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Identifiers>
    <Identifier Name="ProductID" TypeName="System.Int32" />
  </Identifiers>
  <!-- [...] -->
</Entity>
```

That's working. However it has no influence on the "index url". Any hints? Something I have to live with? How do *you* debug this?

**Update:** DisplayUriField sounds like a good thing to look into. Although all I found so far is not what I am looking for. I'm not looking for a way to provide an url myself (where would I link to anyway?!) - I just want the "generated url" to be more meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question in case anyone else is wondering how this works.**

The Method(Instance) Property "**DisplayUriField**" is in fact providing the desired functionality. As a value you can set the name of a TypeDescriptor which is part of your entity schema.

For example if you have a TypeDescriptor like the one below (make sure your SELECT statement returns the column in question)...

```
<TypeDescriptor Name="Url" TypeName="System.String">
  <Properties>
    <Property Name="ShowInPicker" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
  </Properties>
</TypeDescriptor>
```

...you can use it as a value for your DisplayUriField property:

```
<MethodInstances>
  <MethodInstance Name="GetAllProducts" Type="Finder" ReturnParameterName="GetAllProducts_Returned" Default="true" DefaultDisplayName="Get All Products">
    <Properties>
      <Property Name="RootFinder" Type="System.String">x</Property>
      <Property Name="LastModifiedTimeStampField" Type="System.String">ModifiedDate</Property>
      <Property Name="DisplayUriField" Type="System.String">Url</Property>
    </Properties>
  </MethodInstance>
</MethodInstances>
```

My Database Table **Url** column contains urls like this

- http://localhost/adventurworks/catalog/1
- http://localhost/adventurworks/catalog/316
- http://localhost/adventurworks/catalog/317
- [...]

Whatever is in your column will be shown in SharePoints Crawl Log ("Url View").
If your column  ("Url") is nullable and does not contain any value BDC will use a default name for that specific item.

[image: Crawl result with DisplayUriField set for some items]

***Of course after all the custom url is pretty damn useless. However it allows me to figure out whether one specific item has been crawled (successfully) or not because I can relate the shown Url to the ProductID - which I cannot with those bdc3:// urls.***